# Is this navigation pattern a good idea?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, navigation-drawer

I have noticed the following navigation pattern recently and am wondering if this is a "good" pattern in your experience. - Can you point to any usability research about the pattern?

It basically works like this: Show important "shortcuts" as a regular horizontal menu but hide the rest of the site navigation in a "Full menu" drawer. If you have sub sites the visible shortcuts in the horizontal menu can change and reflect the current site you are on. It basically replaces and combine a global menu, utility menu and/or a footer menu.

The pattern could be seen at for example Volvocars.com. A slightly different version of this pattern can also be seen at Microsoft.com

[image: A opened and closed menu drawer on Volvocars.com]

[image: The menu on Microsoft.]

**The benefits** that I can see is the following:

- **Less clutter.** It helps the visitor find the most important pages.
- **Discoverability.** It replaces the footer menu.The users don't have to scroll down to the bottom of the page just to check if there's more content on the site.
- **Easy to maintain.** You could use the same drawer as a hamburger menu on smaller screens.

**The drawbacks**

- **Discoverability.** Do the users actually see and understand the menu?
- **Confusion.** If the shortcuts in the horizontal menu are being repeated in the Full menu do the users think that they are different pages?

What are your takes on this pattern?

Comment: The way this question is asked, it will result in a lot of opinions. If that’s not what you are looking for, maybe you could rephrase the question. For example, are you looking for insights from actual testing?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a great pattern, which is sometimes referred to as an _overflow menu_. It’s also great because it works well on responsive websites: There is no need for breakpoints, as the number of items is always determined by the available space. For example, [Material Design’s Top app bar](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/guidelines) allows for exactly three action icons, the third can be an _overflow menu_. Typically three dots are used as a symbol, a label like  “more” is recommended.

Comment: @Andy You're right. I made a slight clarification about it.

Comment: "is this a good idea" and "what are your takes on X" are the points you should modify in your question. It's still asking people's opinions on the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This type of navigation (dropdown menu or sub-menu) is used for products with a complex hierarchy.
In a nutshell, it is quite difficult to talk about the advantages of such a menu.
I advise you to read these two articles.
Most of the answers you can find in them.

https://www.expandtheroom.com/insights/best-website-navigation-dropdown-menus/

https://designmodo.com/ux-dropdown-navigation-menus/